# Performance testing of frontend JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance-testing

I am tasked with the performance testing of an application, which employs AngularJS on the frontend. The first HTTP request fetches all the functions and all the following interactions with application is served/responded to by the various JavaScript functions.

Any thoughts on how I can test the performance of this application? Essentially I am looking to see if the JS functions are executed within the SLA requirements.

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Comment: [High resolution timers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now).

Comment: you can write tests in angularJS to test your code